# Mocking ruby's Net::IMAP external requests in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, imap

I'm writing specs for a class which has methods to connect to IMAP server and perform some authentication and fetch actions using ruby's `Net::IMAP` class.

I have used [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) gem before in other projects, but it seems to be working only for `Net::HTTP` class. Would like some suggests on some ways to mock the external requests made by the `Net::IMAP` class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how its done in webmock, but if using mocha you can mock IMAP like below.

```
imap = mock('imap')
Net::IMAP.expects(:new).with('imap.gmail.com', 993, true, nil, false).returns(imap)
gmail = Gmail.new('test', 'password')
```

example usage: https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail/blob/master/test/test_gmail.rb

Comment: Thank you. It does let me mock, but not at the level `webmock` would let me to. `webmock` would allow me to the raw response from the external service.